# Run command in bash script while output and capture results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

I'm running an ansible command `ansible-playbook` inside a bash script, but when ansible fails for what ever reason, I need the script to detect this and handle the error (eg. output a defined message and `exit 1`)

I can't seem to fine the best way to still display the output of `ansible-playbook` command, but capture the output to find if there is an error to then exit the bash script?

This is how an failure/error would be detected based on the output of `ansible-playbook`. The full output could be ~100 lines.

```
[0;32m    openstack: PLAY RECAP ***********************************  
[0;32m    openstack: ok=92   changed=73      unreachable=0    failed=1
```

As you can see from the above, `failed=1` indicates a failure, so if `failed=[1-9]+` is there, the bash script should exit.

I've tried using cmds like `tee`, but not having much luck.

Comment: Doesn't `ansible-playbook` have a useful exit code?

Comment: what happens with `ansible-playbook --bad-option; echo statusFromAnsible=$?` ? Good luck.

Comment: @thatotherguy Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: whould `tee` solve your problem ? `ansible-playbook test.yml | tee output.log`

Comment: `if ansible-playbook etc | tee /dev/stderr | grep 'failed=[^0]'; then exit 1; fi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing (Similar to @thatotherguy suggestion)

My code looks similar to this, but not so crude.

```
log=logs/$(date +"%s")
ansible-playbook ... | tee $log
# Do some clean up tasks
if grep -q failed=[^0] "$log"; then
  exit 1
  rm $log
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question how to best capture the output of a command and still display it while executing in a bash script.

But here's a very simple alternative. [Activate logging](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#log-path) in your `ansbile.cfg`:

```
log_path=/var/log/ansible.log
```

Before you start the Ansible run, shred that file. Run Ansible. Then check the logfile for the presence of your pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion @udondan, sadly this won't work in our case as the script could be running concurrently, so the log could contain multiple instances of `ansible-playbook`